# jQuery Plugin: How do I make Pefect Scroll have a Left Scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the perfect scroll plugin but I can't seem to figure out how to make the scrollbar appear on the left side of the div.  Is this an option in the JavaScript?  If not, how can I edit the code to support this?

https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

Comment: Is CSS `overflow-y:scroll;` or JavaScript `Element.style.overflowY = 'scroll';` not working?

Comment: No, I mean left scrollbar vertically.  Not horizontally left and right.

Comment: The Y axis is vertical or height. The X axis is horizontal or width.